# Add Text element on View, using this.state not working - react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, frontend

I'm trying to append  elements to my  in react native, using this.state.

But it **doesn't return the Text element**. My View stays empty...can anyone help?

[I'm using this as a reference.](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-state-array-add-update-remove/)

```
function App() {
  const {register, setValue, handleSubmit} = useForm();
  this.state = {message: []};
  useEffect(() => {
    register('author');
    register('message');
  }, [register]);

  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000/');

  const onSubmit = data => {
    renderMessage(data);
    socket.emit('sendMessage', data);
  };

  socket.on('receivedMessage', function (data) {
    renderMessage(data);
  });

  const renderMessage = data => {
    this.state.message.push(data);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.sectionAuthor}
        placeholder="author"
        onChangeText={text => setValue('author', text)}
      />
      <View style={styles.sectionDescription}>
        {this.state.message.map(item => (
          <Text>{item.author}</Text>
        ))}
      </View>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.sectionMessage}
        placeholder="Message"
        onChangeText={text => setValue('message', text)}
      />
      <Button onPress={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} title="Enviar" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing functional component and class component.

You should use useState to manage state instead of `this.state`

```
  const [messages,setMessages] = useState([]);

  const renderMessage = data => {
    setMessages([...messages, data]);
  };
```

then in your rendering, it should use `messages`.

```
   {messages.map(item => (
      <Text>{item.author}</Text>
    ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function App() {
  const {register, setValue, handleSubmit} = useForm();
  const [message,setMessage] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    register('author');
    register('message');
  }, [register]);

  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000/');

  const onSubmit = data => {
    renderMessage(data);
    socket.emit('sendMessage', data);
  };

  socket.on('receivedMessage', function (data) {
    renderMessage(data);
  });

  const renderMessage = data => {
    let new_msg = [...message];
    new_msg.push(data);
    setMessage(new_msg);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.sectionAuthor}
        placeholder="author"
        onChangeText={text => setValue('author', text)}
      />
      <View style={styles.sectionDescription}>
        {this.state.message.map(item => (
          <Text>{item.author}</Text>
        ))}
      </View>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.sectionMessage}
        placeholder="Message"
        onChangeText={text => setValue('message', text)}
      />
      <Button onPress={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} title="Enviar" />
    </View>
  );
}
```